# How to programmatically control Display Mirroring in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, multiple-monitors

I have come across this function in the Quartz Display Services of Mac OS X:

```
CGConfigureDisplayMirrorOfDisplay
```

But being a real noob in Swift, I am having a hard time figuring out how to use it. This is what I want to accomplish:

I have three monitors hooked up to my Mac. Normally, I want all three to be set up in "extended desktop" mode, but when I launch a presentation in Keynote, I want to have one monitor be the main display, and the other two monitors to show the "Presenter Display."

The only way to do that is to create a mirrored set of the two displays before launching the Keynote slideshow, and then releasing the mirrored set afterward.

I want to do that programmatically. Can anyone give me guidance on how to do that? My plan is to write an applescript script that will watch Keynote call another swift script to enable the mirroring whenever the slideshow is running.

Comment: You can't do this in AppleScript (well apart from GUI scripting), not even in AppleScriptObjC (because most of the Quartz API is written in lower level C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Objective-C code: https://github.com/fcanas/mirror-displays

It is working for me, and I was able to modify it slightly to do what I wanted it to do. I'd love to be able to do this in another language, but this will work for now.

Comment: 1) Please explain what the link covers 2) If you've answered your own question please mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but the real answer for me was to simply move to the newest version of Keynote. The recent versions of Keynote can handle more than two displays seamlessly.